# What protocol or api does the android tv remote control app use?

Tags: android-tv, television, remote-control, anymote

google tv used anymote protocol for remote control but the case with android tv does not looks the same. No official docs clearify if they still use the same. 
I want to develop an app just like the app by google but with some changes and additions mostly on gamepad part. Additionally if anyone knew how apps like cetus play and droid mote for android tv work?
almost similar questions have been asked before as well but never properly answered. Any information and suggestions will be helpul

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)